# Selected option Not Setting in new browser Window Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select, mozilla

```
<select id="country_name" onchange="changeCounty();">
<option value="IND"> IND</option>
<option value="US">US</option>
<option value="JP">JP</option>
<option value="UK">UK</option>
</select>
```

i have the above code.
when i select one option it will do some changes to the page.but when i open the page in new tab of browser the already selected option reset. and default selected option set.How do i cop with this?

Comment: post your javascript

Comment: When you will open the page in new tab, it will get loaded as if it is loading for the very first time. The selected option will ofcourse disappears.

Comment: You need to save the changes and use the changes to set the default. This can be done a few ways depending on 2 things. 1.) When this option is changed are you wanting it to change for everyone that uses the site.  OR 2.) you only want these changes to apply to the users that change them. If you can display more of your source code to show any attempts you have made to set the value (save) that would be great. We debug your code and help you understand the problem and give solutions if any. Here you haven't given us enough information or code to debug.

Comment: @NewToJS .i just want these changes to apply to the users that change them. how save this changes

Answer (score 0):

You need something to pass the value from one page to another, as tabs are by default totally separate pages.

One workaround could be something like this (using LocalStorage) :

```
// Save value when it is changed by user
function changeCounty(){
  if(window.localStorage){
   var inputValue = document.getElementById('country_name').value
   window.localStorage.set('mySavedValueName',inputValue )
  }
  //..your original code
}

// Load value if it exists
window.addEventListener('load', function getContryFromLS(){
  if(window.localStorage){
    var lsvalue = window.localStorage.get('mySavedValueName')
    if(lsvalue)
      document.getElementById('country_name').value=lsvalue 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Html code

```
<select id="country_name" onchange="changeCounty(this);">
<option value="IND"> IND</option>
<option value="US">US</option>
<option value="JP">JP</option>
<option value="UK">UK</option>
</select>
```

JQuery Code

```
 $(function(){
    var d=localStorage.getItem("selectval"); 
    if(d!=null){
        console.log(d);
        $("#country_name").val(d);
   }
    $("#country_name").change(function(){
       localStorage.setItem("selectval",$(this).val());
    });

});
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/d5moqbe7/1/)